# How to open a new Google Colab notebook for R?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I want to be able to create a new Google Colab notebook for R on my own. In previous questions/answers and generally on Internet I see that people leave a link or a blank R notebook that we can use.

Would you please let me know what are the steps to create one on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if Google Colab still allows R, but you can try [this link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BYnnbqeyZAlYnxR9IHC8tpW07EpDeyKR).
Save a copy in your Google Drive, and make any changes you need.

Personally, I recommend using [Kaggle R notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/thimac/rstan?scriptVersionId=20867095) which supports R and Rstan by default.

Answer (score 5):

An easy to remember link

https://colab.to/r

It will redirect to

https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#create=true&language=r

Comment: Please do not use the so-called easy to remember "link" - because you do not know who hosts and maintains the domain colab.to, this is a bad security practice. +1 for the real address though.

Comment: It’s my domain. I maintain it.

Comment: Does not redirect, and the other link shows an empty notebook.